# Target this element with CSS?

Tags: css

Using nth-child, how would I style the `<span class=field-content>Martin McGurk</span>` from the following HTML:

```html
<div id="callout" class="owl-carousel">
 <p>
  <span class=field-content>Good service...</span>
  <span>
   <span class=field-content>Martin McGurk</span>
  </span>
 </p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say, go with:

```css
#callout span .field-content {background: #0cf;}
```

```html
<div id="callout" class="owl-carousel">
  <p>
    <span class=field-content>Good service...</span>
    <span>
      <span class=field-content>Martin McGurk</span>
    </span>
  </p>
</div>
```

Or, if you really prefer `:nth-child`, use:

```css
#callout span:nth-child(2) .field-content {background: #0cf;}
```

```html
<div id="callout" class="owl-carousel">
  <p>
    <span class=field-content>Good service...</span>
    <span>
      <span class=field-content>Martin McGurk</span>
    </span>
  </p>
</div>
```